# Why is the accepted answer, below another (very highly voted) answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, top-network-posts

In [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/405783)  HNQ of Unix and Linux SE, I saw that the accepted answer, with 248 votes, is below another answer with 1382 votes (Yes, I am talking about gimme gimme gimme!) . But as far as my knowledge goes (which doesn't go very far :P), accepted answers flow on top of the list, so why is it happening so in the above linked question? Is it any special feature for an answer with 1000+ or 500+ votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [help page - accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

> [your own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer): No reputation is awarded, and the answer **does not float to the top of the list**. You must wait 48 hours to accept your own answer.

It means if the OP has answered and accepted that question, then it may not list at the top (until if no one has more votes than the accepted answer).

The question you have linked also has the same scenario. OP has self-answered his question. So the highest vote is listed above the accepted answer.