# Accepted answer on very popular question not in the first place

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, answer-order

On this very popular question on Unix.SE: [Why does man print "gimme gimme gimme" at 00:30?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405783/why-does-man-print-gimme-gimme-gimme-at-0030),

the answer by Marnanel Thurman (with approximately 1.6k votes) shows before the accepted answer (by Jaroslav Kucera, with approximately 300 votes).

I am on the sorted by votes tab, which should list the accepted answer first.

Is this a bug, or was it intentionally modified for this question specifically?

Comment: Already asked about the same question with same scenario: [Why is the accepted answer, below another (very highly voted) answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303572/312043)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Self*-answers aren't pinned to the top by acceptance. If you accept your own answer, it'll only appear as the top answer if it's also the highest-voted one.